# Can't use release with ARC enabled

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am making an app and I need a popup alert in it I am using this code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[ UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This is locked" message:@"start with the unlocked content first" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay got it" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

The problem is I can't use "release" with ARC on. Is there anything other than release that I could use in my code?

UPDATE:
Thankyou everyone I just deleted release and then it worked.

Comment: why you need to release it?

Comment: you can remove release. arc will release it for you.

Comment: As others have said, ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) removes the need for making a `release` call for items that are ARC enabled.

Comment: You no need to release any object in ARC enabled project, As ARC itself take care of Releasing the object from memory,

Comment: if you have ACR enabled then no need to write `release` in code.if you write it will produce error.moreever ypu want to write release in class then make this class as non Arc by setting up -fno-objc-arc in bild in pahse

Comment: With Automatic Reference Counting enabled, the compiler will automatically insert retain, release and autorelease in the correct places in your program. You no longer have to worry about any of this, because the compiler does it for you.

Comment: Please don't repost, especially when [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20854666) already got a correct answer.

Comment: I have done what you told me but it still doesn't work

Comment: because I deleted [alert release];

Answer (score 1):

You no need to 
        **release** 
any object in ARC enabled project, As ARC itself take care of Releasing the object from memory.

Although, if you want to use release in your code , or if you want to disable ARC on some particular file than you can add a flag
        **-fno-objc-arc**
on that particular file.

Answer (score 1):

With `Automatic Reference Counting` enabled, the compiler will automatically insert `retain`, `release` and `autorelease` in the correct places in your program. You no longer have to worry about any of this, because the compiler does it for you.

If you keep holding on to all the objects you’ve ever created, then `ARC` will never be able to release them. Therefore, whenever you create a new object, you still need to think about who owns it and how long the object should stay in existence.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to realse when you are using ARC simply remove `[alert relese];` and you than your code work fine.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[ UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This is locked" 
message:@"start with the unlocked content first" delegate:nil 
cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay got it" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

release with ARC not required, that will handle by compiler. Its little tricky as i found my self too when i started but take this great tutorials to understand it better,

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-2

hope this help